# I have to update all the rows in a table. Here is my query

Tags: subquery, mysql-error-1242

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET People_id_Reference = (SELECT People_id 
                           FROM People 
                           RIGHT JOIN top100 
                           ON 
                           People_name=top100.artist ) 
                           WHERE People_id_Reference IS NULL;
```

But I get Error like this:

```
ERROR 1242(21000): SUBQUERY RETURNS MORE THAN ONE ROW
```

Can some on help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: IF I use 'IN' intead of '=' I get sql syntax error 1064(42000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to append a `LIMIT 1` onto the end of the subquery to only force it to return a single row.

Comment: But that inserts same people_id into all rows of People_id_Reference. Is there any other way??

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this :
SELECT * 
  FROM `package_reviews`
  WHERE `post_id` = ANY (SELECT `post_id` 
                     FROM `wp_posts` 
                     WHERE `post_author`=1);
this link is very useful
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html